# Apache NiFi TCP Client/Server

Tags: apache, tcp, server, client, apache-nifi

Can I simulate a TCP client/server interaction using Apache NiFi processors alone or do I have to write code for this? The processors to be considered here are ListenTCP, PutTCP, and GetTCP. In particular, I want to simulate and show a POC for sending HL7 messages from a TCP client to a TCP server. Anyone done this before using NiFi? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ListenTCP starts a server socket waiting for incoming TCP connections. Your client can make connections to the hostname where NiFi is running and the port specified in ListenTCP. If your client needs to send multiple pieces of data over a single connection, then it must send new-lines in between each message. You can simulate a client in NiFi by using PutTCP and pointing it at the same host/port where ListenTCP is running.

UPDATE - Here is an example of the flow:
[image]

Comment: I've tried connecting PutTCP to ListenTCP but NiFi doesn't allow that. And even if I were able to do that, there is no way to specify the source of these messages within the PutTCP configuration.

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't allow that? I have done this test many times, the source of the messages is the content of the flow files going into PutTCP, you can use a generate flow file processor before PutTCP to simulate some fake data.

Comment: What I mean is that I can only create a connection from ListenTCP to PutTCP, not the other way around. PutTCP should be before ListenTCP, right? I have been able to add GenerateFlowFile before PutTCP. Thanks.

Comment: The example I am talking about would be two disconnected flows... on one side ListenTCP is the starting point connected to whatever follow on processors you need, on the other side GenerateFlowFile connected to PutTCP. There is no direct connection on the canvas between PutTCP and ListenTCP, they are communicating over a network connection as if they were in separate NiFi's

Comment: @Foobar see updated answer with a screenshot of what I am talking about

Comment: Bryan, thanks, that worked. I have another related question. How do I specify the number of FlowFiles generated by GenerateFlowFile? I don't see a parameter I can set to specify this. Right now, I have batch size set to 1000 and some text in the custom text field and GenerateFlowFile is generating 269 FlowFiles. Thanks.

Comment: @Foobar it is based on the scheduling strategy, if you have a Run Schedule of 0 seconds then it is running as fast as it can. The Batch Size is supposed to be # of flow files each time it runs, so if you had Run Schedule of 1 seconds, then a batch size of 1000 would be 1000 flow files every 1 seconds.

Comment: Bryan, I still don't understand how GenerateFlowFile determines the number of Flow Files to generate. I have some text in the Custom Text field. Changing the Batch Size, Concurrent Tasks, or Run Schedule has very little bearing on how many Flow Files are generated from the Custom Text. Regardless of what values I use for these parameters, approximately 250 Flow Files are generated. Am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: Bryan, another thing I just noticed. The FlowFiles are of different sizes. Is this the expected behavior with GenerateFlowFile?

Comment: Each flow file produced by GenerateFlowFile will have the content set to the value of the "Custom Text" property, so this property itself has nothing to do with how many flow files are generated. The number of flow files generated is based on the scheduling of the processor that I explained earlier.

Comment: Bryan, thanks. GenerateFlowFile is now working for me but I am now experiencing an issue with ListenTCP which cuts off the last line of streamed text of a message, regardless of what the message text is. My setup is like the diagram you have provided, except that ListenTCP is connected to PutFile. I have tested PutFile with GenerateFlowFile independently of ListenTCP and it retains all the text so I am fairly certain the issue is with ListenTCP. Have you run across this issue before? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Bryan, any information on why ListenTCP would be acting like this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Haven't seen this happen before. If you have a batch size > 1 in ListenTCP then it won't emit a flow file until reaching the batch size, so there could be messages queue internally that haven't been sent out yet.